# Secret agent working for lizard overlords travels through parallel universes

Tags: story-identification, parallel-universe

The universe is made up a infinite parallel timelines where there are small differences between adjacent timelines but the differences get larger the farther from the base time line you travel. The main character is human who is able to speed himself up (hyper speed?) for short periods of time. He is working for a high tech race of lizards (descended from dinosaurs?) who are trying to dominate all the parallel timelines.
read this sometime in the early 1980's

Thanks for the suggestion of Orion by Ben Bova but this isn't it.  The travel between timelines is done with machinery and the hero's ability to to increase his speed was also an implanted system.  The hero starts out working for the Lizards then ends up fighting against them.  The opening chapter starts (if I remember correctly) with the hero trying to steal something out of an office in  a house (maybe) and having a shoot out with the guards.  He is able to move much faster than the normal humans but is hampered by the pistol that he is using can't operate as fast as he can pull the trigger.

Comment: Interesting.  It has some elements in common with the Orion series by Ben Bova.  A human super agent who can speed himself up, Lizard overlords, etc.  But, the travel is more in time than in alternate realities.  Too, Orion is not so much working for the lizard overlords, but against them.                                                                                                              http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orion_in_the_Dying_Time

Comment: @beichst You should submit as a possible answer.  Notice the question doesn't say alternate realities, says timelines.  As far as working for vs against, questioners often times 'misremember' some elements and this was read ~25-30 years ago :)

Comment: @Stan - while there were lizard opponent in one/some books, the main enemies were human-descended "olympians", they were the ones to dominate timelines.

Comment: Hi there, Welcome to Stackexchange! It looks as though you posted this before registering with this Exchange Site, and have just logged in as a different user. I'm looking into merging these accounts.

Comment: Hi again, please see this [help page](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge) on merging your two accounts. Many thanks!

Comment: probably the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/276862/novel-about-a-man-who-moves-between-timelines (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Comment: @Otis I can confirm that the confirmation comment under the answer appears to be the same user.

Answer (score 6):

This probably "At the Narrow Passage" by Richard C. Meredith. If the lizard-like aliens are called the Krith and they can jump across timelines ("skudding") without technology, this is what you want.

Comment: This is it. Now to find a copy to reread.

Comment: @user13605 Welcome to Stack Exchange, in time you will have enough reputation to add comments. For now I've converted your 'answer' to a comment. Don't forget to upvote if it was useful, and mark as accepted if it is correct!

Comment: There are two more in the series; _No Brother, No Friend_ and _Vestiges of Time_

Comment: Richard C. Meredith was diagnosed with cancer while he was writing these; the tone takes a darker turn as it goes along. The ending is poignant, especially if you know he died shortly after finishing *Vestiges*.